# Why might Pinterest not show a pin in a search?

Tags: search, pinterest

A friend of mine promotes his website by pinning pictures of his work on Pinterest. When searching the exact description, they don't show up. At all. Why might this be, and how could I go about fixing it? [This](http://pinterest.com/pin/267049452874322066/) is the pin in question, which isn't shown in a [search](http://pinterest.com/search/?q=Enter+the+underwater+world%21+Balloon+sculpture+of+two+sea+horses+with+the+blue+balloon+arch+on+the+background.+Some+lucky+lady+was+two+years+old+that+day%21+wowballoons.com) of its description.

Comment: how long after the pin was the search performed? Was the search being done within the right category? Are other pins of your friend available via search?

Comment: @Dez: I have found nothing he's pinned by search. "Pinned 11 weeks ago". Where are these categories?

Comment: http://pinterest.com/all/?category=architecture they are available to view if you click the "Everything" word in the top navigation area.

Comment: I see it when I search for the first sentence. http://pinterest.com/search/?q=Enter+the+underwater+world%21

Answer (score 1):

Too many parameters - Pinterest's search apparently limits you to 4 search terms (each word is a term, since [the order is not important](http://pinterest.com/search/?q=Enter%20the%20world%20underwater)), failing completely in case more than 4 words are found on the search query. Pinterest doesn't do full phrase search (using quotes) either.

I'm not sure why your friend needs to do a search based on the description, so it's hard to come up with an adequate solution. However, he can make it work by using the first four words of the description (or any other more unique combination of words found on the description), or [using the "source" search](http://pinterest.com/source/wowballoons.com/).